# best way to import mailing list archives

Tags: emacs, mailing-lists, gnus

I tried reading mailing lists in gnus in emacs, but emacs stops responding with the slow nntp servers downloads.
nabble, gmane etc are also kind of slow.
So I thought about download the gzipped archives available from most mailing lists.
[here](http://johnpoelstra.com/2010/02/10/importing-mailing-list-archives-to-thunderbird/) are some nice instructions to import these archives into thunderbird.  Is there a similar streamlined way to read the unziped archives in emacs, or other software ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `gnus-group-make-doc-group` (`G f` in the `*Groups*` buffer)?

If the files in the archive are in the mbox or similar format it might work.

Another thing to try is to use `gnus-group-browse-foreign-server` (`B`) and pick the correct method and file.